# INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER creating an envelope with notifications

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to create an envelope with an EventNotification, so that I don't have to poll for the status once every 15 minutes.

Making a request to create an envelope without notifications works fine, so it's definitely something to do with the eventNotification part of the request.

Here is the full request:

```
{
  "emailSubject": "Test Sending Envelope 2",
  "eventNotification": {
    "envelopeEvents": [
      { "envelopeEventStatusCode": "sent" },
      { "envelopeEventStatusCode": "delivered" },
      { "envelopeEventStatusCode": "completed" },
      { "envelopeEventStatusCode": "declined" },
      { "envelopeEventStatusCode": "voided" }
    ],
    "includeCertificateOfCompletion": "true",
    "includeCertificateWithSoap": "false",
    "includeDocumentFields": "true",
    "includeDocuments": true,
    "includeEnvelopeVoidReason": "true",
    "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField": "true",
    "includeTimeZone": "true",
    "loggingEnabled": "true",
    "recipientEvents": [
      { "includeDocuments": "Sent" },
      { "includeDocuments": "Delivered" },
      { "includeDocuments": "Completed" },
      { "includeDocuments": "Declined" },
      { "includeDocuments": "AuthenticationFailed" },
      { "includeDocuments": "AutoResponded" }
    ],
    "requireAcknowledgment": "true",
    "signMessageWithX509Cert": "false",
    "url": "https://arealurl/api/DocuSign-NotificationWebHook",
    "useSoapInterface": "false"
  },
  "status": "sent",
  "templateId": "template-guid-4b95-guid-template",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "email": "someone@somewhere.com",
      "name": "Someone Somewhere",
      "roleName": "Something"
    }
  ]
}
```

And the error that comes back is:

```
Error calling CreateEnvelope: {
   "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",
   "message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Boolean value expected for parameter: includeDocuments"
 }.
```

I have tried with the includeDocuments value being omitted, with it set to a string "true", and also with the boolean true as shown above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `recipientEvents` property is incorrect. Change `includeDocuments` to `recipientEventStatusCode`

```
"recipientEvents": [
    { "recipientEventStatusCode": "Sent" },
    { "recipientEventStatusCode": "Delivered" },
    { "recipientEventStatusCode": "Completed" },
    { "recipientEventStatusCode": "Declined" },
    { "recipientEventStatusCode": "AuthenticationFailed" },
    { "recipientEventStatusCode": "AutoResponded" }
],
```

Comment: Of course! I was too busy looking at the main `includeDocuments` field to even consider looking at that section. The SDK has a constructor for the RecipientEvent and EnvelopeEvent classes, and the 2 parameters are the other way around on each, which I didn't spot.